# Why does law of large numbers require the independence in IID?

Tags: probability-theory, independence, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Why does law of large numbers require independence? What happens if the variables aren't independently distributed?

Comment: It doesn't exactly require them to be iid, but if they're too strongly dependent then the sample mean may not converge to the mean of the variables separately (trivial example: $X_n=X_0$), and if their distributions change too much then problems can arise too (an example being $X_n$ independent with distribution given by truncated centered Cauchy distributions, with the removed region shrinking fast enough with $n$).

Comment: Proof Kolmogorov done requires IID. Etamadi showed that given identical distribution and integrability, SLLN holds for pairwise independent random variables. Sometimes for limit to exist it is not necessary for variables to be identically distributed (if they are close enough, Borel Cantelli can help with changing them a bit so that they are identically distributed), however it is hard to say something in general.

Comment: @Ian When you say "mean of the variables," is this mean the population mean, i.e., expected value of the variable?

Comment: Correct, LLN doesn't especially make sense unless all the variables at least have the same mean (I guess you could ask whether the sample mean converges to the Cesaro mean of the population means of the variables?)

Comment: @Ian Ah right. I should clarify my question to be "why independence" is needed rather than IID.

Comment: For that, as I said, $X_n=X_0$ for any nondegenerate distribution shows the point.

Comment: @Ian In this example, are you saying there are 2 random variables, and they happen to be *constrained* to the same realization, and that if you have a bunch of variables with this constraint, then adding more and more variables will never make you any closer to the population mean?

Comment: In this example I'm saying that if you have a "sequence of random variables" that are actually all exactly equal (not just the same distribution but they literally have the same value all the time), and their distribution isn't degenerate, then the sequence of sample means doesn't converge in distribution to any constant (since the sample means have the same distribution as $X_0$ itself).

Comment: Check out de Finetti's theorem, for an example of a related result.

Comment: I published a text about two months ago reviewing some weaker conditions: https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.03967

Answer (score 0):

In [Jan20], I present results for random variables that are not identically distributed and not necessarily independent based on the [approach by Etemadi](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01013465). For instance, the following is true:

**Theorem.** Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of non-negative real random variables such that for $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$ we have

- $\mathsf V S_n \le  c\sum_{k=1}^n \mathsf V X_k$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$ and all $n\in\mathbb N$,
- each $X_n$ has finite variance and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{\mathsf V X_n}{n^2} < \infty$,
- $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{\mathsf E{S_n}}n < \infty$.

Then the $X_n$ satisfy the Strong Law of Large Numbers, i.e.
\begin{equation}
   \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{S_n-\mathsf E S_n}n = 0 \quad \text{almost surely.}
\end{equation}

Additionally, it should be noted that the previous Theorem is wrong if the condition of non-negativity is removed.

---

[Jan20]: Maximilian Janisch, *Kolmogoroff's Strong Law of Large numbers holds for pairwise uncorrelated random variables*. In: Theory of Probability and its Applications, 2021, Volume 66, Issue 2, Pages 263-275. Available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.03967.